# Can't deselect a already selected blank space using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium to reach the target page where the data I'm after is located. My below code can almost get there. I just need a little twitch on it to make it work flawlessly.

Firstly, the browsers leads to a page where a default `Login` button located under `Public User Login` title then it clicks on that button. When a new page appears, It clicks on the `Advanced` tab located on the top of that page under the title of `Account Search`. Upon clicking on that tab there is a list of items visible under the title of `Parcel Classification`. Now, I need to choose `02.C - PROPERTY BURDENED BY CONSERVATION EASEMENTS` from options and press the search button. That's it.

My scraper can do the whole thing accordingly but the problem is: when it selects the preferable option (I've mentioned the text above), there is another option (the very first blank space of those options) by default remains selected. That is why, when my scraper clicks on the search button, it populates wrong results (a page with no results).

How can I deselect the first blank space and continue on with the rest. Thanks in advance for taking a look into it.

The link to that webpage: [Web_Link](http://assessor.coconino.az.gov:82/assessor/web/login.jsp)

This is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("replace_with_above_link")

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#middle_left input[name='submit']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Advanced"))).click()
Select(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tableHtmlLayout #accountTypeID")))).select_by_visible_text('02.C - PROPERTY BURDENED BY CONSERVATION EASEMENTS')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".buttons input[type='submit']"))).click()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you share HTML code sample for the same? Provided URL (at least for me) is not accessible...

Comment: Sure sir. I was waiting for you. Gonna provide a link to the dropbox with the html elements for that portion.

Comment: Link to the html elements for dropdown options: [Click_to_see](https://www.dropbox.com/s/42xzinm7ryi9vp7/Html%20elements.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand the problem correctly, you want to deselect the first option before you select your target option?  How about doing something like this?

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Advanced"))).click()
account_selector = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".tableHtmlLayout #accountTypeID")))
Select(account_selector).deselect_by_index(0)
Select(account_selector).select_by_visible_text('02.C - PROPERTY BURDENED BY CONSERVATION EASEMENTS')
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".buttons input[type='submit']"))).click()
```